# Transferring my OneNote - notebook hyperlinks (links to pdf files) to new pc with a new userpath

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-onenote, mklink

I have a large onenote-notebook that I have been using for study notes. There are many hyperlinks to pdf files. The problem is that all these hyperlinks refer to paths starting with: "C:\Users\RL..." whereas on my new pc, the folder where all my pdf now is located is "C:\User\Ronny...". I did not see this coming when I installed and copied everything from the old pc.

I have checked out the "mklink" command. Maybe something like
mlink /J C:\Users\Ronny  C:\Users\RL
would work? I am scared to do try this and need some advice.

Comment: I'm not sure if this could help, but windows has an environment variable which refers to the user folder named `%USERPROFILE%`. Your links would become something like `%USERPROFILE%\rest\of\path`

Comment: Easier solution would be to reference to OneDrive since your already using that and/or use the Public profile

Comment: I dont whish to edit the hyperlinks since there are so many. Also, it seems to be a lot of work to change the name of my user-folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely create a link and that will work fine. As long as you never create a user of the old name on the PC!

Also, you should make an easily found note of what you did as it is very easy to lose track when you create links like that.

Just remember that if you create a HARD link or a SYMlink, file/folder references in either folder set are the same & deleting in one will delete in the other. The same is not necessarily true if you create a SOFT link ( in that case you can delete the link itself without deleting the original data.

I use "Link Shell Extension" to be able to do this kind of thing direct from Windows Explorer.